# Rcpp - Compile a C++ file with multiple functions

Tags: r, rcpp

I have just quick question about how to compile a .cpp file with multiple function in it.
Let's say I have c++ file like this : Functions.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <math.h>       /* pow */
using namespace Rcpp;

 // [[Rcpp::export]]
 int Function1 (int N, NumericMatrix W){
 return ....
  }

 // [[Rcpp::export]]
 int Function2 (int N, NumericMatrix W){
 return ....
  }
```

and then I would like to compile the file and be able to to call both functions.
I have done it, but what happens is when I try to load the Functions.o it gives me this":

```
 Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Functions.o': 
 LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Anybody , any idea ?

Answer (score 4):

Just use `sourceCpp("nameofyourfile.cpp")`

If you you have no syntax error preventing compilation both `Function1` and `Function2` will be accessible in your R session.

Literally thousands of such files have been written, and almost one hundred are at your disposal over at [the Rcpp Gallery](http://gallery.rcpp.org).

Comment: As I said, I would like to compile my cpp function and make *.o or DLL file out of it and not to compile my functions every time I run my code. I have tried with $sourceCpp()$ and it works fine. The thing is when I load (dyn.load(...)) the *.o file made of this cpp function , it gives the error.

Comment: I have the feeling you are still a little confused, but if you really want to figure out how this works with all the manual steps, you will find them detailed in the [Rcpp book](http://www.rcpp.org/book).  In general you probably want to use a package, or just the simpler ad-hoc `sourceCpp()`.

Comment: Ok, I thought that I need to just go straight to my main point but it seems ....  So I completely understand the differences between sourcing a cpp code, creating a package with skeleton and compile my code with R CMD SHLIB. 

In Rcpp-FAQ and question 2.5 you explained how to compile our code with SHLIB, but imagine that you have more than one function in your cpp file , which you wanted to compile.

Comment: Now, what I'm asking is, why it gives me an error when I try to load the compiled file ?

Comment: I did some search and I found that, I may be able to expose my functions also using RCPP_MODULE. I tried it in my code but I still get the same error. I tried something like that :

   RCPP_MODULE(yada) {
     function("TRIDIA" , &TRIDIA);
     function("BISEC" , &BISEC );
     function("SEB" , &SEB );
     function("SOILTEMPFUN" , &SOILTEMPFUN );
      }
I compiled my code using R CMD SHLIB, and then I loaded the output DLL file, But I still get the same error.

Comment: You have not supplied a reproducible example exhibiting your issue. Lots of people do every day what you claim you cannot do (at least as far as I can decipher your posts). You may want to think providing a well-formulated question on rcpp-devel.